# Google App Engine - Hosting project and website on same server

Tags: google-app-engine, web-hosting, app-engine-flexible

I have a NodeJs App Engine project . I also have an Apache website in another server which hosts the project dashboard. This site is the one using the node API.

I am willing to host both projects on the same server on this Google Cloud project.

Can this be achieved simply by using services in the `app.yaml`?

Answer (score 1):

> I also have an Apache website in another server which hosts the project dashboard.

What does this other server actually do? If it's serving static files, you could easily do this by adding a `static_dir` handler in your `app.yaml`

```
handlers:
# All URLs beginning with /dashboard are treated as paths to
# static files in the web-dashboard/ directory.
- url: /dashboard
  static_dir: web-dashboard
```

If there is actual webserver code running, you could set up and app engine flex with a custom runtime & dockerfile to run apache
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/

But an easier lift would be just rewriting your webserver code to work with one of app engines existing flex runtimes https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/

Once you do that, then you route traffic between the 2 services with `dispatch.yaml`

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml